# fstream::read() read empty if input size too big

Tags: c++

I have tried to read a file by using `istream& read (char* s, streamsize n)`. I have read the description at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/ saying

> If the input sequence runs out of characters to extract (i.e., the end-of-file is reached) before n characters have been successfully read, the array pointed to by s contains all the characters read until that point, and both the eofbit and failbit flags are set for the stream.

Because of that I have put the n with a very large number because I trust the caller that able to allocate enough buffer to read. But I always receive 0 read, I have tried following code to **read txt file with 90 bytes**:

```
std::wstring name(L"C:\\Users\\dle\\Documents\\01_Project\\01_VirtualMachine\\99_SharedFolder\\lala.txt");
std::ifstream ifs;
ifs.open(name, ifstream::binary | ifstream::in);
if (ifs)
{
    // get length of file:
    ifs.seekg(0, ifs.end);
    int length = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg(0, ifs.beg);
    char *buffer = new char[length];


    ifs.read(buffer, UINT32_MAX);
    int success = ifs.gcount();
    cout << "success: " << success << endl;
    cout << "size: " << size;
    ifs.close();
}
```

I even tried with smaller number, eg: 500,000 and it still failed. I have realized that the "n" and the size of file related somehow, the "n" could not be larger than file size too much or else it will read empty....

I know we could fix that easily by putting correct size to `read()` but I wonder why it happened like that? I should read till EOF then stop right? Could anyone explain to me why please?

EDIT: I just simply want to read to EOF by utilizing `istream& read` without caring about file size. According to the definition of `istream& read(char*s, streamsize n)`it should work.

Comment: How big is your file?  If it is more than 90 bytes, you have undefined behavior and any result is valid.

Comment: That file is only 90 bytes, I have even tried to allocate buffer dynamically by the file size but the result is still the same

Comment: try reading 90 bytes instead of UINT32_MAX

Comment: Yes it will work if I read only 90 bytes, but the problem here is I want to have the interface read without caring about the size of file since I trust caller that they could able to allocate correct buffer size. So that I use the fstream:read to do so since it should extracts upto n charcters or EOF(whichever 1st) into any memory location

Comment: If you ask the `ifstream` to put more than 90 bytes into a 90-byte buffer you are asking for undefined behaviour. You need to change the size of your buffer along with the `length` argument to `read()`. In general you need to read streams in loops rather than trying to fit them all into memory at once.

Comment: @DucLe read doesn't allocate any buffer. It will read any number of characters into a buffer that has **already been allocated**.

Comment: @john: yes but it should extract characters to buffer if EOFis reached or n characters is readed (whichever 1st) , this is what is written at   http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

Comment: @DucLe Extracting the characters is not the same as allocating a buffer to put them in. Read will extract the characters but it assumes that you have created a buffer to put them in. Trust me, you are just mistaken. As user207421 says you need to write a loop and **allocate the buffer yourself**.

Comment: @DucLe Three different people have told you that you are mistaken, and your program is failing, what more evidence do you need?

Comment: @john I understand the important of buffer allocation. I have allocated a buffer which is 90 bytes (exact size of file). According to the library definition, it should put the input sequence to that buffer until EOF is reached. If I change UINT32_MAX to some smaller number like UCHAR_MAX or even 50000 (still read 90 bytes) then it works.

Comment: @john I just want to understand the problem of using fstream::read() here. The definition of that library is:  [If the input sequence runs out of characters to extract (i.e., the end-of-file is reached) before n characters have been successfully read, the array pointed to by s contains all the characters read until that point, and both the eofbit and failbit flags are set for the stream.]

Comment: @DucLe OK I misunderstood your question. You should have said that the file is only 90 bytes in the question instead of in the comments. Let me think about it a bit more

Comment: @john sorry for making confusion, I have also edited the code a little bit for better understanding

Comment: @DucLe I took your code, I have to change the filename and I changed `cout << "size: " << size;` to `cout << "size: " << length << endl;` and it worked for me. I used a file of 90 bytes.

Comment: @DucLe OK the problem is `UINT32_MAX`. The second parameter to `read` is a **signed** quantity. You have presumably integer overflow when you use `UINT32_MAX`. The correct code is `ifs.read(buffer, std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());`. `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` gives you that maximum possible read size, it defined in `#include <limits>`.

Comment: @DucLe In the question you said that you tried with smaller numbers and it failed, but in the comments you said that it you tried with smaller numbers and it succeeded. That also confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifs.read(buffer, UINT32_MAX);
```

The second parameter to [`fstream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) is [`std::streamsize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/streamsize), which is defined as (emphasis mine)...

> ...a **signed** integral type...

I therefore *guess* (as I don't have a Windows environment to test on at this point) that you're working on a machine where `std::streamsize` is 32bit, and you're looking at your `UINT32_MAX` ending up as a `-1` (and @john testing on a machine where `sizeof( std::streamsize ) > 4` so that *his* `UINT32_MAX` doesn't wrap into the negative.)

Try again with `std::numeric_limits< std::streamsize >::max()`... or even better yet, use `length` because, well, you *have* the file size right there and don't have to rely on the EOF behavior of `fstream::read` to save you.

---

I am not sure whether C++ changed the definition of streams from what the C standard says, but note that C's definition on binary streams states that they...

> ...may, however, have an implementation-defined number of null characters appended to the end of the stream.

So your, or the user's, assumption that a buffer big enough to hold the data written earlier is big enough to hold the data read till EOF might actually fail.

Comment: I think in the real code the OP does not have the length. So the correct length to use is `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`

Comment: @john: Thanks, edited that `max()` in. I guess I'm doing too much C right now. :-D

Comment: The streamsize in my system is defined as `using streamsize = long long;` so that UNIT32_MAX should not cause any problem. I think your comment about the null characters appended to end of stream may be the root cause of this. Why I am checking for this is because I saw an old code in my project doing this way but still works for years until I touch them. I suspect that they may have some setting on compiler to stop putting null characters to end of stream or using older compiler version..

Comment: @DucLe: The fun of code relying on unspecified, implementation-defined, or downright undefined behavior. ;-) Better playing it safe, always.

Comment: @DevSolar I am still not sure about the actual root cause of it, but interesting things is that code works well with __MSC_VER = 1800 (VS2013) and fails with __MSC_VER >= 1910 (VS2017) (I think it will also fail for 1900 as well) It seems that newer compiler has some optimization which causing the problem with this code. Thanks so much for your support :) (anyway I have fixed this issue to read only <= file size)